# Which grotesque sans-serif fonts are available in TeX Live for the use with pdflatex?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, sans-serif

So far I found:

- Archivo - https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/archivo/
- Droid Sans - https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/droidsans/
- Roboto - https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/roboto/
- TeX Gyre Heros - https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/texgyreheros/

Are there more?

Comment: URW Arial, which is on CTAN but not included in the TeX Live distro.

Comment: And Inter ([\[1\]](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/interregular/), [\[2\]](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter))! Apparently the font is quite new, but still available in TL. But I cannot find it, so there must be something out-of-date about my installation. But more about that would be too off-topic.

Comment: If you're willing to go beyond what is available by default, it's not difficult to set up other fonts with `XeLaTeX`. See, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309712/change-font-size-with-fontspec-package.

Comment: Source Sans Pro as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great listing of [sans-serif fonts at the LaTeX Font Catalogue.](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html)  Ignore any that say “TTF or OTF only.”  A quick browse shows that some others include URW Arial, Cabin, DejaVu Sans, Fira Sans, Source Sans Pro and Universalis.

You can make limited use of the Basic Latin range of a TTF or OTF font in PDFTeX,  You can also convert a TrueType or OpenType font with FontForge and [`fontinst`](https://www.tug.org/applications/fontinst/).  It is also possible to [install any old commercial PostScript fonts you happen to have lying around from the ’90s.](https://texdoc.org/serve/fontinstallationguide.pdf/0)